# how to get current position in XML document

Tags: xml, sax

I am going to read XML elements and store in a B+-tree file, I need to know the position pointer for each element XML to store as nodes in the B+-tree. I want to know how to get these pointers of XML elements during the SAX reads

Answer (score 1):

In your `DocumentHandler` implementation, add an implementation for `setDocumentLocator()` to accept the `Locator` provided by your parser implementation.  This class can be used to query the current position in the document at each SAX event.

Comment: but DocumentLocator give me the column and line numbers for the start document.I want to the absolute position of each each element during the parsing process of XML doc